# Android studio(java) Firebase realtime creating graphs

Tags: android, firebase, graph

I am just wondering how do I create graphs such as pie charts and bar charts, based on my data from firebase real-time. For example, each user is associated with a company I would like to create a bar chart or pie chart based on the total amount of each company for example [pie chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3kiT.png)

Here is what my database looks like [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50JT7.png) [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ifjG.png)

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: this doesn't really have anything to do with firebase, that's just the source of your data, but it's mostly irrelevant here. you have two options, you can either learn how to draw your own charts and graphs or you can make use of a library to achieve this. which library ? that we can't answer here, unfortunately

Comment: @AlexMamo I have not tried much because i am not sure where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve data from firebase database you should check the google docs about it at this [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

It clearly says that firebase use asynchronous listeners, so they will automatically get the data when day are modified.

To create charts in android studio I recommend you to use this external implementation from github, by [PhilJay](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It provides you also all the documentation about the implementation.